# Create map and add additional vector (VectorSources) tiles on top of it (react-native-mapbox-gl)

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Hye,
I want to build a applications using react-native-mapbox-gl and want to do something exactly like this one that use mapbox in web.

https://medium.com/@zhenanhong/creating-map-based-visualization-using-vector-tiles-dbf55d15a7f

I already can display the map but when I added vectorsources and fill layer, nothing did happen..

```js
    return(
     <Mapbox.MapView
       styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Street}
       zoomLevel={10}
       style={styles.container}
       showUserLocation={true}
       userTrackingMode={1}
     >
      <Mapbox.VectorSource>
        <Mapbox.FillLayer
            id='customSourceFill'
            sourceLayerID='vector-source'
            style={stylesMap.boxFill} />
      </Mapbox.VectorSource>
     </Mapbox.MapView>
    )
```

[image]

hoping anyone can provide me guidance to manipulate react-native-mapbox-gl as the example did not work for me.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is it failing silently? What happens when you just add `Mapbox.VectorSource`?

Comment: @ParkerZiegler it's failing silently.. Nothing did happen, the console also did not return any error

Comment: Alright, can you paste the entire contents of the above file. It looks like it should work based on what I've seen in the docs, but it'd be helpful to have the full code!

Comment: Yes.. It work actually, my bad because I change the centerCoordinate, so, actually I need to create my vector Icon inside the mapbox studio.. because when Im using the vector url, it's added on the specific coordinate at Canada. that why I did not see it on my map. btw, tq @ParkerZiegler, right now Im trying to implement hexagon on top of my maps.